# "Can I Run Pro" utility for ESRI ArcGIS Pro does not find existing graphics card

Tags: gpu, nvidia, arcgis, esri

On an AWS EC2 type G with a Tesla 60 graphics card and drivers installed, the "Can I Run Pro" utility https://links.esri.com/run-arcgis-pro fails to find any graphics card.  The msinfo32 shows the graphics card and the Device Manager shows it as well.  I'm concerned that ArcPro 2.5 will not be able to utilize the card and we'll be paying for it for no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, we are running few instances of m4.xlarge and m5 and all we installed the Esri enterprise packates along ArcGIS Pro on the same machine without any major issues. You assume having it running on Type G with a GPU graphics instances should be okay as long you have enough RAM.

I never run "Can I Run Pro" utility and we are running many instances as the ArcGIS Pro as long you have OpenGL drivers installed. Also i am running Pro on a virtual machine on my MAC.